# difference between constructor overloading and chaining in c#

Tags: c#, oop

It is my 1st week OOP, so i am quit new, apologies if the question is on basics, as i can't get my head around it. I don't understand the difference between constructor overloading and chaining. I am using the following parent-class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vehicle_Application
{
abstract class Vehicle
{
    private string color;
    public string Color { get { return color; } set { color = value; }}

    private double fuelTankSize;
    public double FuelTankSize { get {return fuelTankSize;} set { fuelTankSize = value;}}

    private double efficiency; 
    public double Efficiency { get { return efficiency; } set { efficiency = value; } }
    private double fullTankMileage = 100; 
    public double milesPerGalon;
    public void calculateMPG() 
{this.milesPerGalon = (fullTankMileage/(fuelTankSize/4))* efficiency;}

}
}
```

from which the following child class "Car" is driven:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vehicle_Application
{
class Car : Vehicle                            
{                                              
    public Car(string color = null)          
    {       this.Color = color;  }            
    public int NumberOfTyres;
    public Car(string color, int noOfTyres, double fuelTankSize, double efficiency)
    {
        this.Color = color;
        this.NumberOfTyres = noOfTyres;
        this.FuelTankSize = fuelTankSize;
        this.Efficiency = efficiency;
        this.calculateMPG();
    }
}
}
```

the Program looks as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Vehicle_Application
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car car1 = new Car("Red", 4, 5, 6);
        Car car2 = new Car("Red");

        car1.Color = "Red";
        car2.Color = "Green";

        System.Console.WriteLine("The color of the first vehicle is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(car1.Color);

        System.Console.WriteLine("The color of the second vehicle is: ");
        Console.WriteLine(car2.Color);

        Console.WriteLine(car1.milesPerGalon);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Now my confusion comes in constructor `Car`. 
The instances

1. `public Car(string color = null)` and
2. `public Car(string color, int noOfTyres, double fuelTankSize, double efficiency)`

both have different signatures (nr. of parameters) and are both overloaded in `Program` by calling

1. `Console.WriteLine(car2.Color);` and
2. `Console.WriteLine(car1.milesPerGalon);`.

The program recognizes that `car1` has four arguments and therefore uses the 2nd instance of the car. Whereas `car2` has only one argument and therefore the `Program` uses the 1st instance of the car.

The same instances of cars look to my like perfect examples for chaining, as I found examples on the Internet explaining the same process as chaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no constructor chaining involved here, these are simply two different overloads for a constructor.

Constructor chaining would look like this:

```
public Car(string color = null) : this(color, 4, 5, 6)        
{

}     


public Car(string color, int noOfTyres, double fuelTankSize, double efficiency)
{
    this.Color = color;
    this.NumberOfTyres = noOfTyres;
    this.FuelTankSize = fuelTankSize;
    this.Efficiency = efficiency;
    this.calculateMPG();
}
```

Note the `: this()` call on the first constructor. You chain to the other ctor by passing both the color and some default values.

You could also chain to the base class ctor (from Vehicle) if it had one:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle(Color color)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}

public class Car : Vehicle
{

    public Car(Color color) : base(color)
    {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

Correction from InBetween in the comments:

> A constructor of Vehicle must be called always, you can't create a Car
>   without constructing a Vehicle first. What happens is that the default
>   constructor is implicitly called (if there is one) if no other base
>   constructor is called explicitly.

Comment: you really do not need to assign color twice

Comment: Thanks. @Lennart: I understand now that chaining happens by using `:this(xyz)` or when calling from base `:base(xyz)`. My question is: In the 1st line of code in your answer `public Car(string color = null) : this(color, 4, 5, 6) `: Is this a call to the overloaded constructor `public Car(string color, int noOfTyres, double fuelTankSize, double efficiency)`. And in the same first block of code in your answer: the `public Car(string color, int noOfTyres, double fuelTankSize, double efficiency)
{
    this.Color = color;.....`: is this chaning as well or just another constructor whithin `Car`?

Comment: @palm 1: Yes, it is a call to the overloaded ctor. 2: No this is not chaining, this is just another constructor.

Comment: *"That way also the ctor in Vehicle would get called."* This statement is misleading. A constructor of `Vehicle` must be called *always*, you can't create a `Car` without constructing a `Vehicle` first. What happens is that the default constructor is implicitly called (if there is one) if no other base constructor is called explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried using the chained ctor: `public Car(string color, int noOfTyres) : this(color, noOfTyres, 1, 1) {}` in addition to the two ctors in subclass `Car` (see my code above) and in `Program` tried to print: `Console.WriteLine(car3.noOfTyres);`, but i got this error `Error 1 'Vehicle_Application.Car' does not contain a definition for 'noOfTyres' and no extension method 'noOfTyres' accepting a first argument of type 'Vehicle_Application.Car' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Any declaration is appreciated.

Comment: Answer to my question above: the error above is caused by the call made in the `Program`. the `noOfTyres` has to be the `public` declared `NumberOfTyres` so the correct call in `Program` is `Console.WriteLine(car3.NumberOfTyres);` : this will run the program without errors.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C#!

Since you stated this is only your first week at this. I will use a more generic example to help shape your understanding of a few basic construction methods.

Let's say I want to make an object called `Foo`.

```
var foo = new Foo(1);
```

Here are three different ways of designing the class, so that it constructs the **same** object:

### Overloading

```
public class Foo
{
    private int _one;
    private int _two;

    // simple
    public Foo(int one)
    {
        _one = one; // assign the private field "_one" the value passed in
        _two = 0;   // assign the private field "_two" with a default value of 0
    }

    // overloaded (note that the method signature is different)
    public Foo(int one, int two)
    {
        _one = one;
        _two = two;
    }
}
```

### Optional Parameter

```
public class Foo
{
    private int _one;
    private int _two;

    // optional parameter
    public Foo(int one, int two = 0) // if no value is passed into "two", it defaults to 0
    {
        _one = one;
        _two = two;
    }
}
```

### Constructor Chaining

```
public class Foo
{
    private int _one;
    private int _two;

    // constructor chaining (note: 'this')
    public Foo(int one) : this(one, 0) { }

    // constructor
    public Foo(int one, int two)
    {
        _one = one;
        _two = two;
    }
}
```

> All three of these will produce an object called `Foo` with both the private fields set to `_one = 1` and `_two = 2`.

In addition, they allow for you to call the constructor method

```
var foo = new Foo(1,0); // the exact same result (again) as just calling "new Foo(1);"
```